# Predicate logic

Tags: semantics, logic

Is anyone good at predicate logic and can help me to paraphrase the meaning of the following sentences?

1. F=favour D=be a dog P=be a park
   (∀x) (Ǝy) Dx & Py > Fx,y
2. H=hire M=be a manager E=be an employee
   (Ǝx) (∀y) Mx & Ey >Hx,y

My attempt is:

1. All dogs favor to be at least in one park.
2. There is at least one manager who hires all employees.

Do you think this could be correct?

Comment: If it's a class exercise, we should let you have the fun of working it out. But both of these look rather odd, to me.  For the first, try instead  (∀x) ( Dx >  (Ǝy) ( Py & Fx,y ) ), and for the second, try (Ǝx) ( Mx &  (∀y) ( Ey > Hx,y ) ).

Comment: It is okay when the sentences do not make any sense. I've been trying to work it out for hours, but I just don't get it :(

Comment: Using  the first formula I gave above and translating to English, we go from  (∀x) ( Dx > (Ǝy) ( Py & Fx,y ) ) to "For every D there is some P such that the D Fs the P", as a first step.

Comment: Some practice exercises and explanation in the [Logic Study Guide](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf).

Comment: Maybe providing even a very basic answer with the direction to take would be helpful. Unfortunately I don't know anything about this, otherwise I would have answered myself. And @GregLee Those comments would be appropriate for an answer. :)

Comment: @Sarah I added that to your question. Usually edits go there. :D

Comment: Yes, that's right.  (Though the wording is a little clumsy.)  Congratulations.